# URL rewriting in wp fuctions.php without htaccess

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, url-rewriting

Is it possible for URL rewriting in wp fuctions.php without htaccess? I want to convert the below code to standard wp re-write rules.

````
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/acme-challenge/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/cpanel-dcv/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteRule ^photo-gallery/surgical/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/$ wp-content/themes/example-theme/surgical-photo-gallery-details.php?catid=$1&subid=$2&pid=$3```
````

Comment: wordpress cannot rewrite incoming requests by itself. It needs the rewrite module the http server provides. Either by means of a distributed configuration file (often called ".htaccess") or by using the central http server's host configuration. Reason for that simply is that such request would never reach wordpress.

Answer (score 0):

You can add this block of code into your theme’s functions.php file.

```
add_action( 'init', 'add_author_rules' );
function add_author_rules() { 
    add_rewrite_rule(
        "writer/([^/]+)/?",
        "index.php?author_name=$matches[1]",
        "top");
   
    add_rewrite_rule(
  "writer/([^/]+)/page/?([0-9]{1,})/?",
  "index.php?author_name=$matches[1]&paged=$matches[2]",
  "top");
   
    add_rewrite_rule(
  "writer/([^/]+)/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?",
  "index.php?author_name=$matches[1]&feed=$matches[2]",
  "top");
     
    add_rewrite_rule(
  "writer/([^/]+)/feed/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?",
  "index.php?author_name=$matches[1]&feed=$matches[2]",
  "top");
}
```

Comment: Can you please modify the code with exact requirement?